# fill one javascript array with another js array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array `listOfFriends` of objects that contain `[{"name" : "fName lName", "uid" : "0102030405"}], ...`

I want to  cut down the size of this array , since I only need the `uids` , so I would like to make another array with only the `uids`

```
var listOfFriends, listOfFriendsUIDs;
//listOfFriends gets filled

for(var i = 0; i < listOfFriends.length; i++){
  listOfFriendsUIDs[i].uid = listOfFriends[i].uid;  // this line isn't working
  //listOfFriendsUIDs is still undefined untill the start of this loop

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create new array out of IDs:

```
var listOfFriendsUIDs = listOfFriends.map(function(obj) { return obj.uid; });
```

Check the browser [compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Browser_compatibility) and use [shim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Compatibility) if needed.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/x3UkJ/

Comment: @ScottSelby Yes, absolutely.

Comment: that's some pretty sexy code :)  , still learning js , thanks

Comment: @VisioN strictly speaking that's `Array.prototype.map` - `Array.map` would be a (non-existent) class method, not an instance method.

Comment: @Alnitak Yes, I have used `Array.map` just to be shorter.

Comment: suggest you use `myArray.map` or write it in full to avoid ambiguity

Comment: @Alnitak You are too captious today `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Try to use projection method [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
var listOfFriendsUIDs = listOfFriends.map(function(f){ return f.uid;});
```

Answer (score 0):

`listOfFriendsUIDs[i]` is not defined, so you can't access its `uid` property. You either need:

```
// creates an array of UID strings: ["0102030405", ""0102030405", ...]
listOfFriendsUIDs[i] = listOfFriends[i].uid;
```

or

```
// creates an array of objects with a uid property: [{uid:"0102030405"}, ...]
listOfFriendsUIDs[i] = {}
listOfFriendsUIDs[i].uid = listOfFriends[i].uid;
```